# How to implement search based on the multiple columns in Laravel using eloquent way

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a table and need to implement search functionality based on multiple columns.

I have three parameters coming from the `view` `form` and based on these values I need to implement the search in a single table.

`companies` table

```
  id    country    main_category     title
   1       21          30            Hitech
```

I am trying to implement if title `exist` in the `country` and `main_category` only show that `title` if it not exist in that particular column it should return noting and only if `hitech` is coming from the view with `null` `country` and `main_category` than all title matching with `hitech` should return.

What I've tried:

```
$keyword = $request->input('keyword');
$country = $request->input('country');
$sector = $request->input('sector');

$matchThese = ['title'=> $keyword,'country'=> $country,'main_category'=> $sector];

$special_offer = new SpecialOffer();
if(isset($keyword)){
     $special_offer->where("title", "LIKE", "%$keyword%");
}
if(isset($country)){
    $special_offer->where("country", "LIKE", "%$country%");
}
if(isset($sector)){
    $special_offer->where("main_category", "LIKE", "%$sector%");
}

$abc = $special_offer->get();
```

But it does not work exactly as I want.

Comment: can you be a lil bit more clear on what you want, it is very blah so far

Comment: Eloquent is a query builder. You seem  to be asking to build a complicated query where the columns selected depend on the data. The query is complicated, so does the eloquent query builder. I don't think there is a ready made solution in laravel.